# How to hold on pause all Rx-chain's emitted items by condition?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I work with `RxJava` and I want merge my chain with something like `boolean`-flag (in my case `animationRunning`) and hold all emitted items in Rx-chain while animation-flag is `true`.

**Text marble**:

Rx-chain: `---(1)---(2)--------------------------------`

animationRunning:`(true)---------------(false)---------`

Subscribe:`-----------------------------------(1)(2)---`

What do you recommend me for this work?

Comment: Sounds like [`valve()`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersvalve).

Comment: So, one chain is controling with booleans whether the main chains is passing through or buffering. I can't think of a built in operator doing that, but you know you can make your own operators, right? See .lift(). @akarnokd may be right, but then it's a goo opportunity to see how they did it.